# Linux file formats

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition

On my RHEL system, I gave the following command:

```
# file -sL /dev/sd*
```

Here is the output that I received:

```
/dev/sda:  x86 boot sector; GRand Unified Bootloader, stage1 version 0x3, boot drive 0x80, 1st sector stage2 0x849fc, GRUB version 0.94; partition 1: ID=0x83, active, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 1024000 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x8e, starthead 221, startsector 1026048, 103831552 sectors, code offset 0x48
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data (needs journal recovery) (extents) (huge files)
/dev/sda2: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: ZwRo1k6K3XhyqeAUkqQuvMPCoW7leEF
/dev/sdb:  data
```

Request your help in understanding what the above means.

1. Pls validate if this means that I have 2 partitions on my HDD namely, sda and sdb
2. sda is further divided into sda1 & sda2. sda1 is ext4 format type and sda2 is LVM2
3. sdb is of file system type data.
4. What is meant by '***data***' type (in #3) above?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html

Answer (score 2):

You have two disks: sda and sdb.

sda is partitioned: sda1 is ext4 formatted, and sda2 is part of an LVM array.

sdb is (probably) unformatted.

'data' is what `file` reports when it can't work out anything more specific to report.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to waht Douglas has already said...

Also try `lsblk` and `lsblk -f` and `parted /dev/sda print` and `parted /dev/sdb print`. And for a gui, try `gparted`.

`file` is not specialized in file systems and partitions... it is more for files, and probably supports partitions for things like if you had a file that was an image of a disk, you'd see partitions instead of 'data' which is more specific.